# appending under a specific line number using bash

Tags: bash, scripts, playonlinux

I want to append this line:

```
define(\RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', \TCP $h 587')dnl
```

In the **4th** line of a file using bash, I need to do to put in script.

Comment: Is `$h` meant to be interpreted literally, or as the contents of a shell variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
 sed "4i define(\RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', \TCP $h 587')dnl"  {filename}
```

to repalce the content of fole:

```
sed -i "4i define(\RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', \TCP $h 587')dnl"  {filename}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `i` command insert above the addressed line? I would think you'd need `a` for "appending under a specific line number"

Comment: @steeldriver you're right, however the question body says "In the 4th line".